# jQuery .html('') on div moves entire page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm replacing the html in a div tag on my page on the keyup event of a textbox when the user enters a search. When the html is set via jQuery's .html() method on the div tag the entire page shifts to the left and then back to the right. For some reason this is only happening when I deploy the website to an IIS site when I run locally in Visual Studio the page no longer shifts to the left and back to the right. When I replace the div tags content I am first clearing it by calling .html('') and then am setting it to the search results that is a ul tag. This issue is also only happening with Chrome it works fine on Edge.

Comment: show us your code

Comment: There's no need to use `.html("")` first. `.html()` completely overwrites what's already there.

Comment: I've found that when the page shift to the left, it's usually because a scrollbar is being added - usually because the height of your page is changing. Without seeing code it's hard to confirm, so this is just a wild stab in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

Posting code helps, so we do not have to make an assumption on what you are doing.

If you are in fact doing something like:

```
$("#id").html("");
$("#id").html("html-here");
```

Then that makes sense, the first `.html()` call sets the div to be empty, causing the shift you mentioned, then you fill up the div again on the next call to `.html()`.

Using a single call instead will not cause the page to be re-rendered twice, but it will still overwrite the contents like you want (you may have been thinking of `$.append()`, where you do have to clear first:

```
$("#id").html("html-here");
```